# bootstrap-wysihtml5 Integration

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, wysihtml5

I have been using Bootstrap for a while and I was looking for a WYSIWYG text editor. I came across [bootstrap-wysihtml5](http://jhollingworth.github.io/bootstrap-wysihtml5/) on [Github](https://github.com/jhollingworth/bootstrap-wysihtml5/) and thought that it would fit my needs. I looked into how to integrate it with a standard HTML Bootstrap page. It appears that the dependencies for it are [bootstrap-wysihtml5.js](https://raw.github.com/jhollingworth/bootstrap-wysihtml5/master/src/bootstrap-wysihtml5.js), [bootstrap-wysihtml5.css](https://raw.github.com/jhollingworth/bootstrap-wysihtml5/master/src/bootstrap-wysihtml5.css) and [wysihtml5](https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5). I have no problems getting and including the CSS and JS files but I am stuck with wysihtml5. How does one download it and how do you integrate it? I have looked over at http://forums.adobe.com/thread/993552 which has someone who has got it but after a long search I could still not find the files for wysihtml5.

**TL;DR:** Where can I download wysihtml5 and how do I integrate it with a HTML file? Can anyone provide me with a Fiddle to get me started?

Comment: https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5/tree/master/dist is this what you looking for?

Comment: @Tommi Yes! Do you want to submit it as an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: Well, ok. It was easy though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://github.com/xing/wysihtml5/tree/master/dist) is distribution folder with latest compiled scripts.